# UIDocumentInteractionController - our own app shows up in list

Tags: iphone, ipad, iwork, ios

Our app can deal with say Pages files as an example and needs to both hand off files to other applications as well as receive files from other applications.

So we edit the plist CFBundleDocumentTypes to say that we can deal with Pages files. ('Default') mode.

When the user wants to send a .pages file onto another application (Likely the Pages app) then we call UIDocumentInteractionController.

The UIDocumentInteractionController (too) faithfully lists all applications that can deal with .pages files, and WE are on the list. I think that's confusing to the user, why would I use the UIDocumentInteractionController to hand a file off to US? How do we rid ourselves from the list?

Comment: This was fixed in 4.2. I am having the same issue in 4.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One workaround would have been to unregister your application as capable of opening this file type before showing the UIDocumentInteractionController, and register it back after it's dismissed.

But as the document types that your application is capable of opening is specified in the Info.plist with the CFBundleDocumentTypes key, you can't modify it at runtime. Too bad.

I don't see anything else helpful for this in the APIs.

Your best hope is to file a feature request on radar (Apple's bug report database) https://bugreport.apple.com and why not make your request public on http://www.openradar.me to incite others to do the same.

Comment: Thanks. I was waiting for a bit to figure out if this really is a bug (which it is) or some gap in my reading of the API. I have submitted a bug at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I got a response saying that this was a duplicate of another bug, so that means that they know about this issue. I think that in 4.2 or so that this could be fixed.