# iOS Safari File Type Interception (Start My App If User Clicks A Link To My FileType)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I would like to build an iPhone Application that can start itself, should the user click on any file of a certain extention within safari.

I'm asking here because this sounds to me like a tall order, and im guessing I may struggle to find an answer. So I am open to alternate suggestions such as perhaps making use of the UIWebView component?

An example scenario is:
1) User installs my app, and in its settings specifies "*.rss" (Any .rss file)
2) User opens Safari, clicks on a file who's extention is .rss
3) My app opens, and does something with the fully qualified NSURL file

Any advice is appreciated, Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend having a read of Apple's official documentation on the subject

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1

You basically register the type of files your app can process and other apps such as Safari can hand off processing of that file to your app.

Comment: I really appreciate that, the like provedes a great explanation on the majority of my question. However, the only thing im left wondering is exactly where I tell it my file types? Or more specifically, how the user would be able to update the file types that s/he would want my app to intercept? As I understood, the plist is compiled during application build time. Could you help me understand a little more please. I'm sorry if this should have been a new question; I'm very new to fourms like this, Thanks. (P.S. I'm sorry, but it wont let me vote up - need 15 points?)

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to modify the CFBundleDocumentTypes at runtime. The answer to this question says it cannot be done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167590/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-our-own-app-shows-up-in-list